# WooCommerce Composite Products Trying to set SKU on Variation gives "Variation SKU must be unique." error

Tags: plugins, wordpress, woocommerce

I just learned how to create a variable product, and it mostly works, even showing up on the webpage with the proper variations in the dropdown list. Each variation does have an sku #, but when I try to plug that number into the SKU field for each of the two variations, and then click "Save" (and then update the product), I get an error message for each variation, outlined in a red box, saying :

## 7210 – Variation SKU must be unique.

## 7209 – Variation SKU must be unique.

The SKU numbers for each variation are unique. I don't have any products with those sku values on the Products page.

Screen shot of the event, showing both variations, their prices, and the sku numbers I'm entering (note: upon saving & updating the page, the sku numbers will clear from the sku fields, I presume because the plugin thinks they aren't unique sku numbers?)
[image]

Comment: I see I'm getting revenge downvotes because of an answer I gave on another forum. This question has been sitting idle for one month, and suddenly within 18 hours, 3 downvotes. So much for the integrity of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This fixed it for me. In the database, I performed this query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE meta_key LIKE '_sku'
```

At 30 records per page, and 6 pages, on page 6 I found duplicates of the sku #s that were giving errors. In phpMyAdmin I deleted those records, and suddenly I was able to use the correct sku #s on variable products with no errors.

I attribute the solution to this question [url](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/product-sku-must-be-unique-problem-on-products-with-variations?replies=10)